# Data Capturing techniques in Sql server 2005 Express Edition

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using C# and Sql Server 2005 Express Edition.

I am doing logging in my application. Right now I have following two way to do that

1. Enterprise library
2. Manually inserting the logs in tables.

Is there any way to do Data Capturing more efficiently ?

Comment: could you tell us what is inefficient with your current method?

Comment: Too bad that you are using sql server 2005... Sql server 2008 has "Data Capture" which would help you capture better (but not sure if it is "efficient" or not.

Comment: ok Thanks for the reply. can you provide some sample links that descries efficient way of data capturing techniques in 2008

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Pankaj Garg: Both methods given by are superb. Though I have given another method for data capturing.

Answer (score 2):

I know a lot of people dislike triggers, but in my experience they are a very effective and easy way to implement audit logging in SQL. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35933/Implementing-Audit-Trail-using-Trigger) is a good walk through on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library is good. As it also help to gain variety of database connectivity significance

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/)?

SQL Log Rescue is an award-winning log analysis tool, allowing you to explore your logs to view information on database transactions. Additionally, SQL Log Rescue should be kept on hand in case of a potential disaster – if you have accidentally deleted, inserted or modified your database, SQL Log Rescue will help you get the data back.

Also read this: [Tracking Changes in Your Enterprise Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.sql.aspx?pr=blog#id0110011)

Answer (score 0):

Just one note if you go to SQL Server 2008 CDC way, it requires (IIRC, can't find good edition comparison doc now) the enterprise edition.